# Extracting data from table cell with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to extract specific information from table based on which cell is clicked. So far I managed to create a function that works on click. Problem is it always returns the value of the first cell row.

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
            <tr class="bg-info" style="text-align: center">
                <th class="service" data-column="id" data-order="desc">ServiceID &#9660</th>
                <th class="service" data-column="visit.id" data-order="desc">VisitID &#9660</th>
                <th class="service" data-column="visit.vehicle.licensePlate" data-order="desc">License Plate &#9660</th>
                <th class="service" data-column="visit.service.name" data-order="desc">Repair Order &#9660</th>
                <th class="service" data-column="visit.service.name" data-order="desc">Repair Status &#9660</th>
                <th class="service" data-column="visit.service.name" data-order="desc">Repair End Date &#9660</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody id="serviceOrdersTable">
            </tbody>
        </table>

Javascript that builds the table from Ajax Request:
function buildServiceOrdersTable(data) {
        var table = document.getElementById('serviceOrdersTable')
        table.innerHTML = ''
        var text = "To Be Implemented"
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var row = `<tr onclick="clickableRow()" id="test14">
                    <td>${data[i].id}</td>
                    <td>${data[i].visit.id}</td>
                    <td>${data[i].visit.vehicle.licensePlate}</td>
                    <td onclick="clickableRow()" id="test10">${data[i].service.name}</td>
                    <td>${text}</td>
                    <td>${text}</td>
                    </tr>`
            table.innerHTML += row
        }
    }
```

As you can see I tried both on the < tr > and the < td > to enable extraction trough ID. This is the function that is called on click.

```
function clickableRow(){
        alert("test called");
        var serviceID = document.getElementById('test14').innerHTML
        var test10 = document.getElementById('test10').innerHTML
        console.log(serviceID);
        console.log(test10);
        alert("serviceID :: " + serviceID);
    }
```

Both < tr > and < td > always return values from the first table row even when I click 2nd,3rd,4th row etc.

How do I state that I want information not only from the first but from the row I click. Thank you in advance !

Comment: did you try this ? `onclick=``${clickableRow()}``

Comment: @user11195629 how are you expecting that to help?

Comment: I just tried it. It broke the table creation function. I tried numerous things in order this to work. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue you have is that you're duplicating the `id` attributes in the content you create in the loop. This is invalid HTML as `id` have to be unique within the DOM.

To fix this you can instead use a delegated event handler on the `tbody` to handle clicks on the `tr` within it. From there you can traverse the DOM to pull out the relevant information.

As you've tagged the question with jQuery, here's an example using that framework:

```js
let $tbody = $('#serviceOrdersTable')

$tbody.on('click', 'tr', e => {
  let $tr = $(e.currentTarget);
  let rowHtml = $tr.html();
  let serviceName = $tr.find('.test10').text();
  
  console.log(rowHtml);
  console.log(serviceName);
});


function buildServiceOrdersTable(data) {
  var text = "To Be Implemented";
  let html = data.map(item => `<tr>
    <td>${item.id}</td>
    <td>${item.visit.id}</td>
    <td>${item.visit.vehicle.licensePlate}</td>
    <td class="test10">${item.service.name}</td>
    <td>${text}</td>
    <td>${text}</td>
  </tr>`).join('');
  $tbody.html(html);
}

// note data has been minified for brevity
buildServiceOrdersTable([{id: 1,visit: {id: 'visit1',vehicle: {licensePlate: 'foobar1'}},service: {name: 'service1'}}, {id: 2,visit: {id: 'visit2',vehicle: {licensePlate: 'foobar2'}},service: {name: 'service2'}}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr class="bg-info" style="text-align: center">
      <th class="service" data-column="id" data-order="desc">ServiceID &#9660</th>
      <th class="service" data-column="visit.id" data-order="desc">VisitID &#9660</th>
      <th class="service" data-column="visit.vehicle.licensePlate" data-order="desc">License Plate &#9660</th>
      <th class="service" data-column="visit.service.name" data-order="desc">Repair Order &#9660</th>
      <th class="service" data-column="visit.service.name" data-order="desc">Repair Status &#9660</th>
      <th class="service" data-column="visit.service.name" data-order="desc">Repair End Date &#9660</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="serviceOrdersTable"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I see that it works and I shall read trough it carefully. Thank you for pointing out other mistakes I will fix them too. And ofcourse, thank you for the quick answer ! !

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way .

```html
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr class="bg-info" style="text-align: center">
            <th class="service" data-column="id" data-order="desc">ServiceID &#9660</th>
            <th class="service" data-column="visit.id" data-order="desc">VisitID &#9660</th>
            <th class="service" data-column="visit.vehicle.licensePlate" data-order="desc">License Plate &#9660</th>
            <th class="service" data-column="visit.service.name" data-order="desc">Repair Order &#9660</th>
            <th class="service" data-column="visit.service.name" data-order="desc">Repair Status &#9660</th>
            <th class="service" data-column="visit.service.name" data-order="desc">Repair End Date &#9660</th>
        </tr>

        <tbody id="serviceOrdersTable">
        </tbody>
    </table>

<!-- Javascript that builds the table from Ajax Request: -->
<script>
function buildServiceOrdersTable(data) {
    var table = document.getElementById('serviceOrdersTable')
    table.innerHTML = ''
    var text = "To Be Implemented"
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var row = `<tr onclick="clickableRow()" id="test14">
                <td>${data[i].id}</td>
                <td>${data[i].visit.id}</td>
                <td>${data[i].visit.vehicle.licensePlate}</td>
                <td onclick="clickableRow()" id="test10">${data[i].service.name}</td>
                <td>${text}</td>
                <td>${text}</td>
                </tr>`
        table.innerHTML += row
    }
}   

// function clickableRow(){
        // alert("test called");
        // var serviceID = document.getElementById('test14').innerHTML
        // var test10 = document.getElementById('test10').innerHTML
        // console.log(serviceID);
        // console.log(test10);
        // alert("serviceID :: " + serviceID);

        const selectTr = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
        for(items of selectTr){
            items.addEventListener("click",e=>{
                console.log(e.target.innerText);//for clicked table data
                console.log(e.toElement.parentElement.innerText)//for clicked table row
            });
        }
    // }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! It works perfectly!